# why when put images on drawable v24 app crashes

Tags: android, android-studio

> When put images on drawable v24 app crashes , and use the same image
>   in drawable work correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Look at which line your app is crashing in Logcat. You will be calling the resource file like this: `R.drawable.yourresource`. In this case it will work fine. If you change this line to `R.drawableV24.yourresource` and place the resource file in drawable V24 folder, it will work.

It all depends on how you identify the resource file :)

Answer (score -1):

> Please check your image drawable folder if the image in drawableV24 so transfer it in an only drawable folder and check it

Image resources placed in the res/drawable/ directory may be automatically optimized with lossless image compression by the aapt tool during the build process.

for more detail [click here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/drawables#ColorExtract)